# how to extract key and values from a specific script using its name

Tags: python

I'm trying extract key data from this specific script amoung other n number of script:

```
<script>
        window.PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP = {
            productSelectionData: {"products":[{"part":"ABC0123","dimensions":{"bag-dimensionCaseSize":"XL","watch_cases-dimensionCaseMaterial":"nylon","watch_cases-dimensionColor":"blue","watch_cases-dimensiontype":"carryon"},"priceKey":"bag_cases-nylon-XL-carryon"}]}};
```

the code i have tried:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"window.PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP\s+=\s+(\{.*?});\n")
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
data3 = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data3)
print(data3.keys())
```

But this is not working i'm getting error:

```
data3 = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What do you think `text=pattern` tells `soup.find`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Find the script with the tag window.PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP and load it data to text

Comment: And what do you base that conclusion on?

Comment: the code i'm using is sourced from somewhere else. So my understanding might be wrong all together. If you can help it fix it. it will be a big help. Thank you

Comment: You might want to look at the BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: sure thing, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to parse this JavaScript data to Python dict:

```py
import json
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = """\
<script>
        window.PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP = {
            productSelectionData: {"products":[{"part":"ABC0123","dimensions":{"bag-dimensionCaseSize":"XL","watch_cases-dimensionCaseMaterial":"nylon","watch_cases-dimensionColor":"blue","watch_cases-dimensiontype":"carryon"},"priceKey":"bag_cases-nylon-XL-carryon"}]}};
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")

# locate the <script> tag:
s = soup.script

# get JavaScript text from the script tag using `re`
data = re.search(r"PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP = (.*);", s.text, flags=re.S).group(1)

# correct some JavaScript -> Json
data = data.replace("productSelectionData", '"productSelectionData"')

# use Json parser
data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "productSelectionData": {
        "products": [
            {
                "part": "ABC0123",
                "dimensions": {
                    "bag-dimensionCaseSize": "XL",
                    "watch_cases-dimensionCaseMaterial": "nylon",
                    "watch_cases-dimensionColor": "blue",
                    "watch_cases-dimensiontype": "carryon",
                },
                "priceKey": "bag_cases-nylon-XL-carryon",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Code for the provided URL:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-orange-ocean-band-onesize"
html_string = requests.get(url).text

# get JavaScript text from the script tag using `re`
data = re.search(
    r"PRODUCT_SELECTION_BOOTSTRAP = (.*?});", html_string, flags=re.S
).group(1)

# correct some JavaScript -> Json
data = data.replace("productSelectionData", '"productSelectionData"')

# use Json parser
data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "productSelectionData": {
        "displayValues": {
            "watch_cases-dimensionCaseSize": {"variantOrder": ["49mm"], "49mm": {}},
            "watch_cases-dimensionCaseMaterial": {
                "titanium": {},
                "variantOrder": ["titanium"],
            },
            "prices": {
                "watch_cases-titanium-49mm-gpscell": {
                    "comparativeDisplayPrice": 'From <span class="nowrap">$799</span>',
                    "amount": 799.0,
                    "promoSavings": None,
                    "fullPrice-comparative": '<span class="as-pricepoint-fullprice">From <span class="nowrap">$799</span></span>',
                    "acmiPrice-comparative": '<span class="as-pricepoint-installmentprice-comparative">or $66.58<span aria-hidden="true">/mo. </span><span class="visuallyhidden"> per month</span><span class="nowrap acinstallment-term-length"> for 12 <span aria-hidden="true">mo.</span><span class="visuallyhidden">months</span><span class="as-price-acinstallmentterms-footnotes"><span class="visuallyhidden">Footnote</span>*</span></span><span class="as-price-acinstallmentterms-footnotestext"> Terms apply.</span></span>',
                    "acmiPrice": '<span class="as-pricepoint-installmentprice"> or $66.58<span aria-hidden="true">/mo. </span><span class="visuallyhidden"> per month</span><span class="nowrap acinstallment-term-length"> for 12 <span aria-hidden="true">mo.</span><span class="visuallyhidden">months</span><span class="as-price-acinstallmentterms-footnotes"><span class="visuallyhidden">Footnote</span>*</span></span><span class="as-price-acinstallmentterms-footnotestext"> Terms apply.</span></span>',
                    "previousPrice": None,
                    "currentPrice": {"amount": "$799.00", "raw_amount": "799.00"},
                    "fullPrice": '<span class="as-pricepoint-fullprice"><span class="nowrap">$799</span></span>',
                    "tierListSavings": None,
                    "seoPrice": 799.0,
                }
            },
            "watch_cases-dimensionColor": {
                "titanium": {
                    "image": {
                        "scaleFactor": "RETINA",
                        "srcSet": {
                            "src": "https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/watch-49-titanium-ultra2_SW_COLOR?wid=64&hei=64&fmt=jpeg&qlt=90&.v=1692834364399",
                            "scaleParams1": "wid=32&hei=32&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&.v=1692834364399",
                        },
                        "attrs": "",
                        "alt": "",
                        "width": "32",
                        "height": "32",
                        "imageName": "watch-49-titanium-ultra2_SW_COLOR",
                        "originalImageName": "",
                        "noImage": False,
                        "deferSrc": False,
                    },
                    "text": "Titanium",
                },
                "variantOrder": ["titanium"],
            },
            "watch_cases-dimensionConnection": {
                "variantOrder": ["gpscell"],
                "gpscell": {},
            },
        },
        "watchProductSelectionDataNoJS": [
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-orange-ocean-band-onesize",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Orange Ocean\xa0Band",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-alpine-loop-large",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue Alpine\xa0Loop - Large",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-green-gray-trail-loop-m-l",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Green/Gray Trail\xa0Loop - M/L",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-ocean-band-onesize",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue Ocean\xa0Band",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-olive-alpine-loop-medium",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Olive Alpine\xa0Loop - Medium",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-indigo-alpine-loop-small",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Indigo Alpine\xa0Loop - Small",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-alpine-loop-medium",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue Alpine\xa0Loop - Medium",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-olive-alpine-loop-large",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Olive Alpine\xa0Loop - Large",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-indigo-alpine-loop-large",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Indigo Alpine\xa0Loop - Large",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-alpine-loop-small",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue Alpine\xa0Loop - Small",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-orange-beige-trail-loop-sm",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Orange/Beige Trail\xa0Loop - S/M",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-olive-alpine-loop-small",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Olive Alpine\xa0Loop - Small",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-white-ocean-band-onesize",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with White Ocean\xa0Band",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-green-gray-trail-loop-sm",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Green/Gray Trail\xa0Loop - S/M",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-black-trail-loop-m-l",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue/Black Trail\xa0Loop - M/L",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-orange-beige-trail-loop-m-l",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Orange/Beige Trail\xa0Loop - M/L",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-indigo-alpine-loop-medium",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Indigo Alpine\xa0Loop - Medium",
            },
            {
                "url": "https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-blue-black-trail-loop-sm",
                "text": "Apple Watch Ultra 2 GPS + Cellular, 49mm Titanium Case with Blue/Black Trail\xa0Loop - S/M",
            },
        ],
        "selectButtonText": "Continue",
        "namedAssets": {"watch_cases-dimensionColor_selectedLabel": "Finish"},
        "sections": [],
        "priceDisplayOrder": {
            "full": ["fullPrice-comparative", "acmiPrice-comparative"],
            "short": ["fullPrice", "acmiPrice"],
        },
        "products": [
            {
                "part": "MRFU3LL/A",
                "dimensions": {
                    "watch_cases-dimensionCaseSize": "49mm",
                    "watch_cases-dimensionCaseMaterial": "titanium",
                    "watch_cases-dimensionColor": "titanium",
                    "watch_cases-dimensionConnection": "gpscell",
                },
                "priceKey": "watch_cases-titanium-49mm-gpscell",
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but i'm still getting the error.. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @skywalker Did you locate the right `<script>`? Surely there will be many in the page.

Comment: @yes there are many other script but this is a unique one with tht tag name. I'm try to find the script using the codes since the location number of this script changes from one product url to another.

Comment: @skywalker Then you can use `s = soup.select_one('script#ID_NAME')` or some other method. It's hard to guess without seeing the  URL or original HTML.

Comment: here is the sample url https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch-ultra/49mm-cellular-titanium-orange-ocean-band-onesize

Comment: @skywalker I've updated my answer.

Comment: WoW!. Amazing.... Its working perfectly. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255513/discussion-between-skywalker-and-andrej-kesely).